# MySQL slowlog optimsing for Having and Group By Keywords

Tags: mysql, query-performance, slow-log

I have below entry in the slow-log, i just wonder how can i optimise this below query as it looks very simple query that, i don't see any way of optimising it,

```
# Query_time: 32.797535  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 512871
use dbname;
SET timestamp=1629724372;
SELECT *
FROM `screening`
JOIN `referrals` ON `referrals`.`a_id` = `screening`.`screen_id`
JOIN `referrals_file` ON `referrals_file`.`a_id` = `referrals`.`a_id`
GROUP BY `screening`.`screen_id`
HAVING (MONTH(MIN(referrals_file.datereceived)) = 12 and YEAR(MIN(referrals_file.datereceived)) = 2021);
```

- (please mind am not a database administrator, just developer so my knowledge will be limited)

Comment: Having condition can be simplified to: `WHERE referrals_file.datereceived BETWEEN '2021-12-1 0:0:0' AND '2021-12-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: Please say in words what the query is trying to do.  (The query needs a major rewrite -- to start by finding the oldest referral, but I don't know what to do next.)

Comment: 12/2021 is some time in the future -- that does not jive with the column name "datereceivED"

Answer (score 1):

At first look, I would:

- be sure there is an index for both columns `referrals`.`a_id` and `screening`.`screen_id`
- Do the calculation of `MIN(referrals_file.datereceived)` in a [WITH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) block, for example like this:

```sql
WITH ref_file AS (
    SELECT a_id, MIN(datereceived) AS dtMin
    FROM referrals_file
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT *
FROM `screening`
JOIN `referrals` ON `referrals`.`a_id` = `screening`.`screen_id`
JOIN ref_file ON ref_file.`a_id` = `referrals`.`a_id`
WHERE MONTH(ref_file.datereceived) = 12
AND YEAR(ref_file.datereceived) = 2021;
```

(not sure this compiles, as I do not have the database to test^^)

And I would perhaps avoid using `MONTH()`  and `YEAR()`, to avoid calling functions that could slow a bit. I would go for something like this:

```sql
WHERE ref_file.datereceived LIKE '2021-12-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this on `referrals_file`:

```
INDEX(datereceived, a_id)
```

And use a sargeable expression.  Then write the query so that the Optimizer is likely to start with finding a_ids that have been received next December.

```
SELECT s.*, rf.*
    FROM ( SELECT a_id
               FROM 
               GROUP BY a_id
               HAVING MIN(datereceived) >= '2021-12-01'
                  AND MIN(datereceived)  < '2021-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
         ) AS x
    JOIN `screening` AS s  ON s.screen_id = x.a_id
    JOIN `referrals_file` AS rf ON rf.`a_id` = x.`a_id`
```